# Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Azure Service Bus breaks tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream, spring-test

Adding a dependency to

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder-servicebus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

suddenly makes **some** of my RestTemplate client tests fail with errors like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$"
Expected: (a collection containing <152> and a collection containing <153>)
     but: a collection containing <152> was String "<UnmodifiableRandomAccessList><item>152</item><item>153</item></UnmodifiableRandomAccessList>"
```

or

```
Expected :application/json
Actual   :application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

My tests look like:

```
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init()
    {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        mockServer.expect(requestTo(url))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasItems(152, 153)))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body("{}")); // actual code removed for brevity
        
        ResultDTO result = client.makeRestCall(Set.of(1L)); // beneath makes a RestTemplate call to the url

        assertNotNull(result);
    }
```

What is weird is that only some of the tests in a tests class fail, i.e., this class has 8 tests, out of which 4 fail, without a discernable cause. What I see is that I remove the Azure dependency, tests pass. Does anyone have a clue about what that dependency brings that could break my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is [a known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/416). The problem is that the Azure dependency brings in the `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency that breaks the format of the rest controller responses (makes them XML instead of the default JSON). The simple fix for the issue is excluding the dependency:

```
<exclusion>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>              
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
</exclusion>
```

The thread mentions that the dependency has been made optional, but I couldn't find the version in which that happened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your **spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder-servicebus** dependency like this, by adding extension:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder-servicebus</artifactId>
        
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```